# Rails 3 fields_for has_one not rendering form fields with devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello Im using devise to register users, and I want to create a profile related to a user every time a user signs up, the problem is that when I try to add the full name of the person from the profile model on the registration view for devise's user registration, it does not show up...

This are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_attributes

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  # attr_accessible :title, :body 
end
```

This is the profile model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :phone, :code
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user
end
```

And this is the devise view modified:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up' ) %>
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: resource %>

      <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
        <%= profile_form.label :full_name %>
        <%= profile_form.text_field :name %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

  </div>
</div>
```

I cant see anything wrong to why the name text field would not appear...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, it was so simple I feel bad... so here it is:

I forgot to generate a new profile on the form so it ends up looking kind of like this:

```
.
.
.

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: resource %>

      <div class="invisible">
        <%= resource.build_profile %>
      </div>

      <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
        <%= profile_form.label :full_name %>
        <%= profile_form.text_field :name %>

      <% end %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %> 

.
.
.
```

Hope this solves someone else's problem as well!

Thank you!

Comment: I'd only add for posterity that resource.build_profile might be better placed in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered, but I thought I'd throw this up as an alternative for others.  Form backing objects can be used to go back to a one form/one model kind of setup and help keep code cleaner.

Here's a good writeup on it:
http://pivotallabs.com/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit/